# URL encode sees “&” (ampersand) as “&amp;” HTML entity

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I am encoding a string that will be passed in a URL (via GET). But if I use `escape`, `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent`, `&` will be replaced with `%26amp%3B`, but I want it to be replaced with `%26`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the string come from? Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: `&amp;` is the proper way to escape the ampersand in an HTML context...where is your source coming from? and what's the destination? It may be better to do this server-side for example.

Comment: I grap something from the HTML body (and that is HTML encoded (so, there is &amp; I realize now)) and I have to pass it in an URL... So, I need to decode the html (but how?) en then encode the string (with encodeURIComponent)...

Comment: found it... I used in jquery .html(), not .text()... stupid (A)

Comment: jQuery's *.html()* maps to the *innerHTML* property, so the issue is as I said in my answer :-)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to answer other than a stab in the dark.  I would guess that the string you're passing to `encodeURIComponent()`, which is the correct method to use, is coming from the result of accessing the `innerHTML` property.  The solution is to get the *innerText*/*textContent* property value instead:

```
var str, 
    el = document.getElementById("myUrl");

if ("textContent" in el)
    str = encodeURIComponent(el.textContent);
else
    str = encodeURIComponent(el.innerText);
```

If that isn't the case, you can usethe *replace()* method to replace the HTML entity:

```
encodeURIComponent(str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&"));
```

Answer (score 104):

If you did literally this:

```
encodeURIComponent('&')
```

Then the result is `%26`, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/srepH/).  Make sure the string you are encoding is *just* `&` and not `&amp;` to begin with...otherwise it is encoding correctly, which is likely the case.  If you need a different result for some reason, you can do a `.replace(/&amp;/g,'&')` before the encoding.

Comment: ... that is probably his problem.

Answer (score 8):

There is HTML and URI encodings. `&amp;` is `&` [encoded in HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Character_references) while `%26` is `&` in [URI encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

So before URI encoding your string you might want to HTML decode and then URI encode it :)

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '&amp;AndOtherHTMLEncodedStuff';
    
var htmlDecoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
console.log('htmlDecoded: '+htmlDecoded);
    
var urlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(htmlDecoded);
console.log('urlEncoded: '+urlEncoded);
```

result `%26AndOtherHTMLEncodedStuff`

Hope this saves you some time

Answer (score -1):

Just to be clear, you should ***never*** be using `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`.  If you disagree, just look at its results...

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('@#$%^&*'));
```

> Input: `^&*`.
>
> Output: `%40%23%24%25%5E%26*`.

That's not right, is it?  `*` did not get converted!  I hope you're not using this as a server-side cleansing function, because `*` will not be treated as input but as commands, i.e., imagine deleting a user's alleged file with `rm *`.  Well, I hope you're not using encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent()!

TLDR: You actually want [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`fixedEncodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

[**MDN encodeURI() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)...

> ```
> function fixedEncodeURI(str) {
>    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
> }
> ```

[**MDN encodeURIComponent() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)...

> ```
> function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
>  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
>    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
>  });
> }
> ```

With these functions, use `fixedEncodeURI()` to encode a single URL piece, whereas `fixedEncodeURIComponent()` will encode URL pieces and connectors; or, more simply, `fixedEncodeURI()` will not encode `+@?=:#;,$&` (as `&` and `+` are common URL operators), but `fixedEncodeURIComponent()` will.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `encodeURIComponent` was supposed to “cleanse” anything? It encodes text to preserve its meaning in a URI. It’s not for passing user input directly to `system("rm")`. What?

Comment: You can actually use the results of these functions with anything.  That's just an example.  You can run this server-side with NodeJS.  And then run server-side commands with URL inputs.  It's designed this way, no?

Comment: If you wanted to assemble user input into a shell command and not have globs expanded, the function to use would be an `escapeshellarg`-style one. Also, you should literally never assemble user input into a shell command.

Comment: That was just an example.  You may need to run user-input as args somewhere.  This is the proper way to do the escaping with JS.

Comment: No, it’s really not. This is a dangerous misunderstanding of the purpose of encoding.

Comment: How about I completely remove anything shell-related in my example?  And instead do a simply forloop over chars available in js, showing that I can't use encodeURI() to access the `%2a.html` file?