# Where to find information on SOAP/XML queries for Microsoft Dynamics CRM API

Tags: xml, api, soap, dynamics-crm

I'm working on a project for a client that wants to integrate their web site (built in PHP) with their Microsoft hosted Dynamics CRM 2011.

I've found a great resource here for connecting to the Dynamics server and pulling very basic information out of the database (contact / accounts):

-> http://www.21logs.com/php-and-microsoft-dynamics-crm-source-code/

I spent a bunch of time today looking for information on the other types of SOAP/REST queries that I would need to use to either pull more information or add/update information in the database and I came up pretty snake-eyes.

If anyone knows of a resource that has some additional XML example queries for playing around with Dynamics CRM data it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it isn't technically the repository of information that I was originally looking for, I did find the following blog post

-> http://www.zenithies.org/articles/1/connect-to-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-web-service-from-php-using-ifd-authentication.html

Which lead me to this : http://www.zenithies.org/articles/articles/6/microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-php-integration-offer.html

Zenithies offers a PHP class for sale for a reasonable price (i.e. way less than I could have charged a client to research & write the same code) that lets you connect to Dynamics CRM using PHP and perform contact adds, edits and searches.

Nothing too complicated but everything I needed to hook a web site user login / self-manage address information up to a Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

I have purchased the package and tried it myself and verified that it does in fact work. I would suggest that anyone stuck in a situation where they need to connect a PHP web site and Microsoft Dynamics CRM consider just making the same purchase.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you all the info constructing FetchXML queries

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms936573.aspx

And if you are interested in the FetchXML schema

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms955990.aspx

Comment: So am I to understand that the SOAP interface is incapable of updating records? Only retrieving them?

Comment: They look interesting resources, but MS seem not to have provided any context navigation on those pages. Is there a parent article that links to them? I can't see any links back to any.

Answer (score 0):

You can get most of the data by modifying the fetchxml in the query. What kind of data are you interested?

Comment: I guess in that case, I'm looking for a resource on fetchxml

Answer (score 0):

Look at the slightly Modified version of the Dynamics PHP SDK I pushed to GitHub.

https://github.com/epinapala/MsDynamicsPHP

The SDK provided by Dynamics does not work out of the box(at the time of writing this.)  and it needed changes.

Hope this helps.

Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Dynamics if you click the "Advanced View" filter, you can select whatever data you like and have the system auto-generate fetchXML for you. I created an R script that uses that to extract data from Dynamics using the web API they provide.

The entire script is posted below, hopefully some of you will find it helpful. It's hard to overstate how difficult this Web API is to work with, it was gigantic pain to figure all this out.

I work in a corporate environment, so you'll see a lot of code about authenticating through proxies, etc.

[image]

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Introduction
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Purpose: Download data from Microsoft Dynamics using a fetch XML request
# Created: 2/23/2021
# Modified: 10/1/2021
# Author: Ryan Bradley 
#
# Resources on this topic:
# https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/master/R/oauth-token.r
# https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth2-azure.r
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
# https://blog.r-hub.io/2021/01/25/oauth-2.0/
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/webapi/discover-url-organization-web-api
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/retrieve-and-execute-predefined-queries#use-custom-fetchxml
# https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/378416/resource-not-found-for-the-segment-error-getting-custom-entity-from-common-data-service-web-api
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/introduction-entities#:~:text=The%20entities%20are%20used%20to,Engagement%20(on%2Dpremises).&text=An%20entity%20has%20a%20set,%2C%20Address%20%2C%20and%20OwnerId%20attributes.
# https://datascienceplus.com/accessing-web-data-json-in-r-using-httr/
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/url-encode-sees-ampersand-as-amp-html-entity
# https://www.inogic.com/blog/2019/04/handling-special-characters-while-executing-fetch-xml-programmatically-in-web-api-rest-call/
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/url-encode-sees-ampersand-as-amp-html-entity
# https://truenorthit.co.uk/2014/07/dynamics-crm-paging-cookies-some-gotchas/
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ First time set up and maintenance 
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#...........................................................................................
#.. Encode your active directory user name and password with key ring
#...........................................................................................
# This is only relevant if you need to authenticate through a proxy.
#
# You will need to install the keyring package and set your active directory user name
# and password. You can run remove the comments from the 4 lines below and run them to
# install the package and set your AD user name and password.
#
# You will also need to repeat these steps when your active directory information changes.
#
# install.packages("keyring") 
# library(keyring)
# keyring::key_set("id")
# keyring::key_set("pw")
#
#...........................................................................................
#.. Get a token to authenticate with Microsoft Dynamics
#...........................................................................................
#
# 1. Log into the azure portal
#     https://portal.azure.com/#home
# 2. Register a new app
# 3. Generate a client secret on the "Certificates & secrets" page. Save it for later.
# 4. Create an application scope on the "Expose an API" page. 
# 5. Grant the app "user_impersonation" access to "Dynamics CRM"
# 6. Meet with the an Active Directory IT administrator, and have them click
#  "Grand Admin consent for Consumers Energy" on the "API Permissions" page of your app.
#
# If all those steps worked, you should now be able to authenticate using the code below.
#

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Hard-coded variables
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Define global setting for importing strings as factors
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
options(httr_oauth_cache=T)

#...........................................................................................
#.. Azure App Data
#...........................................................................................
# Found here:  https://portal.azure.com/#home

# Azure app ID
# Source: "Overview" tab of your application in the Azure portal
client_id <- "YOUR ID" 

# App name
# Source: "Overview" tab of your application in the Azure portal
app_name <- "MY_APP" # not important for authorization grant flow

# Secret ID
# Source: "Clients & Secrets" tab of your application in the Azure portal
client_secret <- "YOUR SECRET"

# Application ID URI.
# Source: "Expose an API" tab of your application in the Azure portal
application_id_uri = "YOUR URI "

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Load or install packages
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Load or install librarian
if(require(librarian) == FALSE){
  install.packages("librarian")
  if(require(librarian)== FALSE){stop("Unable to install and load librarian")}
}

# Load multiple packages using the librarian package
librarian::shelf(tidyverse, readxl, RODBC, lubridate, httr, XML, jsonlite, rlist, httpuv, quiet = TRUE)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~  Set up global httr proxy configuration
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# This is only needed if you're connecting through a proxy 

# set_config(use_proxy(url="yourproxy.com",port= 1234
#                      ,username=keyring::key_get("id")
#                      ,password=keyring::key_get("pw")
#                     )
#             )

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Authenticate with Dynamics
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Use the default Azure endpoints default ones
azure_endpoint <- oauth_endpoints("azure")

# Create the app instance.
myapp <- oauth_app(
  appname = app_name,
  key = client_id,
  secret = client_secret
)

# Step through the authorization chain:
#    1. You will be redirected to you authorization endpoint via web browser.
#    2. Once you responded to the request, the endpoint will redirect you to
#       the local address specified by httr.
#    3. httr will acquire the authorization code (or error) from the data
#       posted to the redirect URI.
#    4. If a code was acquired, httr will contact your authorized token access
#       endpoint to obtain the token.
mytoken <- oauth2.0_token(azure_endpoint,
                          myapp,
                          scope = application_id_uri,
                          cache = str_cache
)

if (("error" %in% names(mytoken$credentials)) && (nchar(mytoken$credentials$error) > 0)) {
  errorMsg <- paste("Error while acquiring token.",
                    paste("Error message:", mytoken$credentials$error),
                    paste("Error description:", mytoken$credentials$error_description),
                    paste("Error code:", mytoken$credentials$error_codes),
                    sep = "\n"
  )
  stop(errorMsg)
}

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Begin making requests
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#...........................................................................................
#.. Dynamics API data
#...........................................................................................

# The URL of the Dynamics instace you'd like to connect to
base_url <- "https://YOURPLATFORM.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/"

# This part of the URL is added on to the base URL to use the web API 
# to send on a fetchxml request
url_add_on <- "?fetchXml="

# XML retrieved by downloading fetch XML from Microsoft Dyanmics using the "Advanced Find" view. 
# You may need to edit the auto-generated XML, it's not always great. Consider making the alias
# something legible, like I did below.
#
# I copied and pasted the XML into notepad and used find and replace to escape all the quotes.
# " -> \"
#
# Make sure your "order attribute" XML code is unique to every row in the data set. 
# If it's not, if may cause issues when pulling data with more than 5,000 rows.
#
xml <- "<fetch version=\"1.0\" output-format=\"xml-platform\" mapping=\"logical\" distinct=\"false\">
  <entity name=\"amendments\">
    <attribute name=\"seasonyear\" />
    <attribute name=\"enrollmenttype\" />
    <attribute name=\"effectivestartdate\" />
    <attribute name=\"effectiveenddate\" />
    <attribute name=\"contractstartdate\" />
    <attribute name=\"contractenddate\" />
    <attribute name=\"program\" />
    <attribute name=\"programduration\" />
    <attribute name=\"programtype\" />
    <attribute name=\"kwnominations\" />
    <attribute name=\"renewalkw\" />
    <attribute name=\"newkw\" />
    <attribute name=\"account\" />
    <attribute name=\"ownerid\" />
    <attribute name=\"amendmentsid\" />
    <attribute name=\"statuscode\" />
    <attribute name=\"statecode\" />
    <attribute name=\"amendment\" />
    <attribute name=\"name\" />
    <order attribute=\"amendmentsid\" descending=\"false\" />
    <link-entity name=\"salesorder\" from=\"salesorderid\" to=\"order\" visible=\"false\" link-type=\"outer\" alias=\"sales\">
      <attribute name=\"datecontractapproved\" />
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name=\"account\" from=\"accountid\" to=\"account\" visible=\"false\" link-type=\"outer\" alias=\"account\">
      <attribute name=\"accountmanager\" />
      <attribute name=\"accountnumber\" />
      <attribute name=\"statecode\" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>"

# Encode the XML into a URL
url_xml <- URLencode(xml)

# Set the dynamics entity/table you wish to use. 
# Entities = Dynamics tables, and attributes = Dynamics columns
# NOTE: MUST BE PLURAL. If your entity is "contact" then put "contacts" and if
# your entity already ends in "s" try adding "es." Example -> amendments -> amendmentses
#
# You should be able to find the entity name in the first or 2nd line of an auto-generated
# XML. Example:   <entity name=\"amendments\">
dynamics_entity <- "amendmentses"

# Create a Web API query URL
url_fetch <- paste0(base_url, dynamics_entity, url_add_on, url_xml)
# url_fetch

# Send GET request. 
resp <- GET(url = url_fetch
            , config(token = mytoken)
            , add_headers(Prefer = "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"") # This header is required to get legible text returned along with a paging cookies (if applicable)
)

#...........................................................................................
#.. Check for a valid API response
#...........................................................................................
if(http_error(resp) == TRUE){
  print("Authentication error, unable to proceed.")
} else {
  
  # Convert the hexadecimal content response to a string
  resp_json <- rawToChar(resp[["content"]])
  
  # Decode the JSON response
  resp_list <- fromJSON(resp_json)
  
  # Extract the data frame values into a stand-alone data frame
  df_data_raw <- resp_list[["value"]]
  
  # Extract paging cookie data (This is only passed if there is more than 1 page of results.
  # by default an API query is limited to 5000 rows, so any extra rows are on additional 
  # pages that need to be queried.)
  paging_cookie_resp <- resp_list[["@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie"]]
  
  # Check for a paging cookie
  if(length(paging_cookie_resp) == 0){
    print("No paging cookie returned, only one page of results.")
  } else {
    
    print("Retrieving multiple pages of results.")
    
    # Set the starting page number
    page_number <- 1
    
    # Create a variable to determine when we've found the last page of data
    last_page_found <- FALSE
    
    while(last_page_found == FALSE){
      
      #...........................................................................................
      #.. Retrieve multiple pages of results (only applies to data sets with > 5,000 rows)
      #...........................................................................................
      # Split the paging cookie data into a list
      lst_paging_cookie_resp <- str_split(paging_cookie_resp,"\"")
      
      # Retrieve the double-URL-encoded paging cookie
      encoded_paging_cookie <- lst_paging_cookie_resp[[1]][4]
      
      # The paging cookie is DOUBLE url-encoded, so you first need to decode it TWICE. (What a pain this was to figure out)
      decoded_paging_cookie <- URLdecode(URLdecode(encoded_paging_cookie))
      
      # Split the de-coded paging cookie data into a list (so we can extract the page number)
      lst_decoded_paging_data <- str_split(decoded_paging_cookie,"\"")
      
      # If the paging cookie comes in double-quotes, remove the the quotes at the 
      # beginning and end of the string
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_remove(decoded_paging_cookie,"^\"")
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_remove(decoded_paging_cookie,"\"$")
      
      # Replace any special characters with their HTML equivalents 
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_replace_all(decoded_paging_cookie,"&","&amp;")
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_replace_all(decoded_paging_cookie,"<","&lt;")
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_replace_all(decoded_paging_cookie,">","&gt;")
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_replace_all(decoded_paging_cookie,"\"","&quot;")
      
      # URI encode to the paging cookie (This must be done so the API can receive it)
      URI_encoded_paging_cookie <- encodeURIComponent(decoded_paging_cookie)
      
      # Increment the page number by 1
      page_number = page_number + 1
      
      # Create a URL-encoded fetch-XML header that we can add into the existing the URL-encoded XML that 
      # We originally sent to the API
      xml_header <- "paging-cookie=\"PutPagingCookieHere\" page=\"PutPageNumberHere\" distinct="
      url_encoded_xml_header <- URLencode(xml_header)
      
      # Splice in the URI-encoded paging cookie and page number
      url_encoded_xml_header <- url_encoded_xml_header %>%
        str_replace("PutPagingCookieHere",URI_encoded_paging_cookie) %>%
        str_replace("PutPageNumberHere",as.character(page_number))
      
      # We now have the paging cookie and page number in the appropriate URL and URI encoded formats. 
      # We can now splice this extra information into the XML header of our original API request. 
      new_url_xml <- str_replace(url_xml,"distinct=",url_encoded_xml_header)
      
      # Create a new Web API query URL with the updated XML data
      url_fetch <- paste0(base_url, dynamics_entity, url_add_on, new_url_xml) 
      # url_fetch
      
      # Retrieve the next page of data
      resp <- GET(url = url_fetch
                  , config(token = mytoken)
                  , add_headers(Prefer = "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"") # This header is required to get legible text returned
      )
      
      # Check for an error returned in the response
      if(http_error(resp) == TRUE){
        
        print("Error while retrieving 2nd page of results, unable to proceed.")
        last_page_found <- TRUE
        
      } else {
        
        # Convert the hexadecimal content response to a string
        resp_json <- rawToChar(resp[["content"]])
        
        # Decode the JSON response
        resp_list <- fromJSON(resp_json)
        
        # Extract the data frame values into a stand-alone data frame
        df_data_raw_next_page <- resp_list[["value"]]
        
        # The API only returns columns that hold data. To make sure our columns match, 
        # we need to add any columns missing from either data frame to the other data frame
        # so we can join them.
        
        # Add any columns missing from the original data frame to the new one
        prev_page_names <- names(df_data_raw)  # Vector of columns you want in this data.frame
        missing <- setdiff(prev_page_names, names(df_data_raw_next_page))  # Find names of missing columns
        df_data_raw_next_page[missing] <- NA                    # Add them, filled with NA results
        
        # Add any columns missing from the new data frame to the original one
        next_page_names <- names(df_data_raw_next_page)  # Vector of columns you want in this data.frame
        missing <- setdiff(next_page_names, names(df_data_raw))  # Find names of missing columns
        df_data_raw[missing] <- NA                    # Add them, filled with NA results
        
        # Append these rows onto the original data frame and
        # filter out any extra rows from the join
        df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
          rbind(df_data_raw_next_page, use.names=TRUE) %>%
          filter(`@odata.etag` != "TRUE") %>%
          distinct()
        
        # Extract paging cookie data (This is only passed if there is more than 1 page of results.
        # by default an API query is limited to 5000 rows, so any extra rows are on additional 
        # pages that need to be queried.)
        paging_cookie_resp <- resp_list[["@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie"]]
        
        # Note if we're on the last page of results so we exit the loop
        if(nrow(df_data_raw_next_page) < 5000){
          last_page_found <- TRUE 
        } else {
          print(paste0("Page ",page_number," retrieved, retrieving page ", page_number + 1))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  #...........................................................................................
  #.. Clean the returned column names
  #...........................................................................................
  
  # Keep formatted columns only, removing the non-formatted versions from the data frame.
  # The API gives 2 versions of each formatted column, a formatted version and a non-formatted version with the GUID.
  # We only want the formatted version, since that's readable to the human eye. We don't want a GUID.
  
  # Set the starting index to 1
  i <- 1
  
  # Loop over the columns in the data frame
  while(i <= length(names(df_data_raw))){
    
    # Extract the current column name
    str_col_name <-names(df_data_raw)[i]
    # print(paste0("Cleaning column ",i," - ",str_col_name))
    
    # Proceed if we have a column returned
    if(is.na(str_col_name) == FALSE){
      
      # Check for unwanted meta data columns we can remove
      condition_1 <- grepl("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
      condition_2 <- grepl("Display.V1.AttributeName",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
      condition_3 <- grepl("@odata_etag",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
      condition_4 <- grepl("@odata.etag",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
      
      # Check to see if an unwanted column has been found
      if(condition_1 | condition_2 | condition_3 | condition_4){
        
        # Remove the column
        df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
          select(-all_of(str_col_name))
        
        # Reset the index since a column was removed
        i <- 0
        
      } else {
        
        # Check to see if it's formatted column
        if(grepl("@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)){
          
          # Extract the base column name by removing the huge suffix "@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"
          str_base_col <- str_replace(str_col_name,"@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue","")
          
          # Remove the base column if it exists (leaving us with only the formatted version of 
          # the column, not the original version of it.)
          df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
            select(-all_of(str_base_col))
          
          # Reset the index since a column was removed
          i <- 0
          
        } else {
          str_base_col <- str_col_name
        }
        
        # Remove any prefixes or suffixes from the column name
        str_new_col <- str_replace(str_base_col,"_","") # Remove "_" prefix
        str_new_col <- str_replace(str_new_col,"\\.","_") # Replace any periods with an underscore
        str_new_col <- str_replace(str_new_col,"_value$","") # Remove "_value" suffix
        
        # Re-name the old column name to the new one
        df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
          rename(!!str_new_col := all_of(str_col_name))
        
        # If this is a character column that has the word "date" in it attempt to convert it to the 
        # a date-type column. 
        if(grepl("date",str_new_col,ignore.case = TRUE) & typeof(df_data_raw[,i]) == "character"){
          
          print(paste0("Attempting to convert ",str_new_col," to a date format."))
          # Attempt to assign the proper data type
          df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
            mutate(attempt_mdy = mdy(!!as.symbol(str_new_col))) 
          
          # If we had at least 1 successful conversion, convert the
          # column to the date format
          if(sum(is.na(df_data_raw$attempt_mdy) == FALSE) > 0){
            df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
              mutate(!!as.symbol(str_new_col) := attempt_mdy)
          }
          
          # Drop the attempt_mdy column
          df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
            select(-attempt_mdy)
        }
      }
    }
    # Move up the index to the next column
    i <- i + 1
  }
  
  # Select desired columns
  df_data <- df_data_raw %>%
    select(contract_account_number = account_accountnumber       
           , program_duration = programduration
           , contract_start_date = contractstartdate
           , contract_end_date = contractenddate
           , season_year = seasonyear
           , state_code = statecode
           , status_code = statuscode
           , account
           , account_state_code = account_statecode
           , program
           , name
           , kw_new = newkw
           , kw_renewal = renewalkw
           , kw_nomination = kwnominations
           , account_manager = account_accountmanager
           , contract_approval_date = sales_datecontractapproved
           , enrollment_type = enrollmenttype
           , effective_start_date = effectivestartdate
           , effective_end_date = effectiveenddate
           , owner = ownerid
           , program_type = programtype
           , amendment
           , amendment_id = amendmentsid
    )
  
  # Set numeric data types
  df_data <- df_data %>%
    # Remove commas
    mutate(season_year = gsub(",","",season_year)
           , kw_new = gsub(",","",kw_new)
           , kw_renewal = gsub(",","",kw_renewal)
           , kw_nomination = gsub(",","",kw_nomination)) %>%
    # Convert to numeric values
    mutate(season_year = as.numeric(season_year)
           , kw_new = as.numeric(kw_new)
           , kw_renewal = as.numeric(kw_renewal)
           , kw_nomination = as.numeric(kw_nomination))
  
  # Add a load_date_time column
  df_data$load_date_time <- Sys.time()
  
  
}
```