# 403 FORBIDDEN ajax calling script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript URL encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/javascript-url-encode)

some scripts working fine started to give me this error.

It is probably due to some special chars inside the string passed.

Ajax is calling this:

```
.../ControllerAjaxSpecifiche.php?Material=100%%20poliester&product=Maglia (trikot)
```

this way it says 403 forbidden error

removing the % and () it works

```
.../ControllerAjaxSpecifiche.php?Material=100%20poliester&product=Maglia trikot
```

How I can solve this problem?

I tried passing those variables as post, buit it did not works, and I continue having same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `encodeURI(...)` or `encodeURIComponent(...)` on the parameters?

Comment: material=100%...  should go to material=100%25... when you are using url_encode the right way

Comment: Solved differently to avoid any problem with string. SENT Data with ".ajax with post, so no intereferences with routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `urlencode()` (php) or `encodeURI()  encodeURIComponent()` (js) before passing the values. This should escape any harmful characters

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to format your links correctly