# How to use RFC2822 format date in a URL?

Tags: url, get, rfc2822

How do I pass date in RFC2822 format, to an URL in GET method:

e.g I want to pass 18th jan 2013 as min_date_created in the URL https://www.xyz.com/orders

18th jan 2013 in RFC format is ==> Fri, 18 Jan 2013 17:58:49 +0000

how can I pass it to URL?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the date as a string, you could convert it to the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970:

```
var time = new Date('Fri, 18 Jan 2013 17:58:49 +0000').getTime(); // 1358531929000
widow.location.href = 'https://www.xyz.com/orders?min_date_created='+time;
```

This way you won't have encoding problems.

Or you could also use `encodeURIComponent()`, see [URL encode sees “&” (ampersand) as “&amp;” HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/javascript-url-encode)