# Spotify Web API special characters

Tags: api, http, url, encoding, spotify

Is there any documentation for the Spotify Web API as to which characters are valid when searching?  For example "Macklemore & Ryan Lewis" needs the & to be url encoded in order for the request to work.

The character ":" is completely invalid it seems.  In order to search for an album like "Pink Friday:  Roman Reloaded", I have to remove the : completely from the String.  Even URL encoding it doesn't work.  This probably was to do with the fact that : seems to be used to separate the fields of the query.

Other characters like .[()/ seem to work ok.  Any docs on this anywhere?  Just want to know we are being comprehensive. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the Björk example [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/search),

```
http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist?q=artist:Bj%C3%B6rk
```

You'll need [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  Not sure what technology you're using, if javascript, this answer should help - [URL encode sees “&” (ampersand) as “&amp;” HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/javascript-url-encode).

Update:

Colons are special characters used for [advanced search](https://support.spotify.com/us/learn-more/faq/#!/article/Advanced-search1/?in=search).  Queries involving colons need to be quoted, unless it's an advanced search :).

Comment: I don't think it will accept a percent encoded colon character.  For example, Nicki Minaj's album, "Pink Friday:  Roman Reloaded".  This URL works  http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.json?q=album:Pink%20Friday%20Roman%20Reloaded (The colon is taken out completely).  But the following does not (returns zero results) http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.json?q=album:Pink%20Friday%3A%20Roman%20Reloaded (that one has a percent encoded colon as %3A).  And as expected, it doesn't work if you just put a non-encoded colon.

Comment: I've seen some complaints on IRC about similar things.  I suspect there's some undocumented rules about making search work best.  I'd probably cut out all punctuation.

Comment: Putting quotes around the title with colon does work: http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.json?q=album:%22Pink%20Friday%3A%20Roman%20Reloaded%22

Comment: Oh, and sorry I didn't read your question clearly enough.  You already knew about url encoding.