# html - correct way to append json to a link

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hi I have a code which uses facebook login:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="no" height="600" scrolling="auto" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
client_id=183620578322567&
redirect_uri=http://example.com/store_user_data.php?&
fields=[
{"name":"name"},
{"name":"email"},
{"name":"password"},
{"name":"gender"},
{"name":"birthday"},
{"name":"captcha"}
]"
scrolling="auto"
frameborder="no" 
style="border: none;" 
width="500"
height="600">
</iframe>
```

as you can see the json part(fields) in the src attribute is something wrong with a quote missing possible but I'm unable to attach it, so how would be the correct way? thnks

Comment: your `redirect_uri` should be URL-encoded as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover all the possible points regarding your question, check that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some does and don't regarding your issue:

- **don't use** `escape()`, its been deprecated since ECMAScript v3.
- **Use** `encodeURI()` instead. you can also use `decodeURI()` in the way round.
- **don't use** `encodeURIComponent()` to escape all the url string, since it would ruin your URL, **use** it just when you want to send a url as a paramter.
- **don't use** `'` for the attributes in your json, **use** `"` instead, because the mentioned functions does not encode the `'` character.

for instance, you can add your json to the url, and then call `encodeURI`:

```
var url = 'http://myhost.com/?{"key", "value"}';
var myEncodedurl = encodeURI(url);
//result-->http://myhost.com/?%7B%22key%22,%20%22value%22%7D
```

but

```
encodeURIComponent(url);
//result-->http%3A%2F%2Fmyhost.com%2F%3F%7B%22key%22%2C%20%22value%22%7D
```

then using `encodeURIComponent` would help you if you want to send all that `url` as a parameter, like this:

```
var myEncodedurl = 'http://myotherhost.com/?myurl=' +
                    encodeURIComponent('http://myhost.com/?{"key", "value"}');
//result-->http://myotherhost.com/?myurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmyhost.com%2F%3F%7B%22key%22%2C%20%22value%22%7D
```

BTW, for your sample you'd better try:

```
var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?client_id=183620578322567&redirect_uri=' +
encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/store_user_data.php?&'
+ 'fields=['
+ '{"name":"name"},'
+ '{"name":"email"},'
+ '{"name":"password"},'
+ '{"name":"gender"},'
+ '{"name":"birthday"},'
+ '{"name":"captcha"}'
+ ']&"'
+ 'scrolling="auto"'//extract it from encodeURIComponent if they belong to your original url
+ 'frameborder="no"'//extract it from encodeURIComponent if they belong to your original url
+ 'style="border: none;"'//extract it from encodeURIComponent if they belong to your original url
+ 'width="500"'//extract it from encodeURIComponent if they belong to your original url
+ 'height="600"'/*extract it from encodeURIComponent if they belong to your original url*/);
```

Comment: I'd say `encodeURIComponent` is the correct one for query strings.

Comment: you'r right but other than this, there are some points that I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should properly escape the whole string. Use the JavaScript `encodeURIComponent()` function.

There are more information about javascript url escaping here: [URL encode sees “&” (ampersand) as “&amp;” HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/javascript-url-encode)

Comment: Just note that `encodeURIComponent` was not meant to escape whole URIs, it should be applied to every query string parameter value (and parameter name) which needs escaping.

Answer (score 1):

at the basic level, you need to change src="..." to src='...' so that the double quotes inside your JSON aren't used to close the src attribute.   However, you should really url encode all special characters in the url and try to avoid carriage returns in your url.