# Send a variable containing "&" or "%" to a PHP page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I've got a Javascript script that sends 4 variables to a php page.

The fact is that, if one (or more) of these variables contain a character such as "&" or "%", it just
won't work, it only sends what there was before "&" or "%". For instance, if the content of a variable is 
"Bolliger&Mabillard", the result will be "Bolliger". Obviously, this happens because the script separate each
variable with an "&", how can I solve this?

Here's the script I'm talking about

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function save() 
{ 
 var shortname=location.hostname.replace(/^(www.|)([\w]+)(\..+|)/g, "$2");
 var url="http://"+window.location.hostname+"/";
 var link=window.location.href;
 var link_title="Bolliger&Mabillard"; 
 window.open("http://www.example.com/add.php?url=" + url + "&shortname="+shortname + "&link="+link + "&link_title="+link_title);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/javascript-url-encode

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage". That doesn't even make _sense_.

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL-encode the values using `encodeURIComponent()`.