# Generating QR code of an URL

Tags: opencart

I have used Google chart and the LGPL QR code class for php to generate the QR code for an URL, but both fail to generate a correct for the URL below:

`http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx/index.php?route=sale/order/invoice&order_id=4&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

The result of the QR code after scanning will be something like

`http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx/index.php?route=sale/order/invoice&amp;order_id=4&amp;token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Is there any way to avoid the `amp;` to appear?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem; both URLs in the question seem to be exactly the same?

Comment: @Codor It's formatted wrong. Look at the markdown and you'll see that one is `&token` and the other is `&amp;token`

Comment: How are you scanning the QR code? If from smartphone, what is the name of the app? Also, can you link us the QR-code (with fake data but same URL construction)?

Comment: I think you're using Opencart's url helper to generate the URL? If so, read through my answer to this (seemingly unrelated) question http://stackoverflow.com/a/27262139/1301076 I suspect you have exactly the same problem

Comment: `&amp;` is a HTML-Code for `&` - consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/url-encode-sees-ampersand-as-amp-html-entity

You can also look into my answer about QR-generation in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68385427/4575793

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, wheter it helps you. Reason is that I have some difficulties to understand your question.
Maybe this javascript helps you generating you URL, I am using it as bookmark.

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'Qr code','top=100,left=200,width=350,height=350,status=yes'));
```