# Opencart: Cannot call controller with $this->url->link and curl

Tags: curl, opencart

I want to call a page using cUrl like this:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0; // set to zero for no timeout
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url->link('account/order/invoice', 'order_id=20'));
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $invoice = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

This does not work. "order_id=20" is not passed through to the controller.
This does work:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0; // set to zero for no timeout
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://webshop.local/index.php?route=account/order/invoice&order_id=20');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $factuur = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

When I echo $this->url->link('account/order/invoice', 'order_id=20'), the URL is correct.

I don't see any difference. I could use the second method, but the first is more correct for creating urls in opencart.

I would like to know what I do wrong or why it works like this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to add an invoice to the order mail. The url gives me an html page of the invoice. Using dompdf I turn it into a pdf.

Comment: Either use your working code (nothing wrong with that) also, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159122/best-method-to-send-get-params-to-url-and-get-returned-results-in-php (I'm marking this as a duplicate).

Comment: You could just render the route instead of using curl, which will require you to log in as the customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is that the URLs are **NOT THE SAME**.

Check the code in /system/url.php:

```
if ($args) {
    $url .= str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&')); 
}
```

Your generated URL will be:

`http://webshop.local/index.php?route=account/order/invoice&amp;order_id=20`

compared to your hand-written one:

`http://webshop.local/index.php?route=account/order/invoice&order_id=20`

That's because the helper is designed to **output URLs intended for use in HTML**, where the `&amp;` will be correctly parsed. Echo out your generated link and view the page source, or look at your shop links and you'll see what I mean.

If you dig deeper and look at the top of the account/account controller, you'll see this:

`$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));`

The redirect helper (in system/engine/controller.php) actually has to *convert the `&amp;s` back again* before it can use the URLs created by the URL helper:

`header('Location: ' . str_replace(array('&amp;', "\n", "\r"), array('&', '', ''), $url));`

Frankly, it's a bit of a mess, but that's what you have to work with.

So if you want to use the URL helper, I suggest you do the same thing as OpenCart itself:

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, str_replace('&amp;', '&', $this->url->link('account/order/invoice', 'order_id=20')));`